# Problems replacing GRUB2

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

After Windows ate my GRUB2, I replaced it using the GUI boot-repair method posted here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. I clicked the "recommended method" button and followed all the steps successfully. Ubuntu 13 boots fine now, but I seem to remember there being more items in my GRUB2 list. There was MEMTEST and maybe more? Those things weren't replaced.

Comment: please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5841119/

Comment: could someone at least tell me what I'm missing out on please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Ubuntu and my Grub2 menu is back to normal. A few MEMTEST items were added.